# How to get current culture in sharepoint 2013 online

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have two site collections one is for english and other is for norwegian.Everything is working fine on English site collection but when it comes to norwegian then not everything is working. trying to upload one file in Site Assets. its working perfectly on english site but it dont upload file on norwegian site collection. When debug code on norwegian bokmål site then i can see that current culture remains en-US ... its soo strange . Anybody have expereince ??
here is my code

```
 public void UploadFile(ClientContext ctx)
    {
        try
        {
            var filename= "/SiteAssets/myfile.js";
            var filePath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + @"Scripts\myfile.js";

            Web web = ctx.Web;

            CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            Console.WriteLine("The current culture is {0} [{1}]",
                         culture.NativeName, culture.Name);

            string lib = "Site Assets";
            if (culture.Name == "en-US")
            {
                lib = "Site Assets";
            }
            else if (culture.Name == "nb-NO")
            {
                lib = "Nettstedsobjekter";
            }
            else if (culture.Name == "nb")
            {
                libraryTitle = "Nettstedsobjekter";
            }

            List assetLibrary = web.Lists.GetByTitle(lib);
            ctx.Load(web);
            ctx.Load(assetLibrary, l => l.RootFolder);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
            newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            newFile.Url = "myfile.js";
            newFile.Overwrite = true;

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadAsset = assetLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
            ctx.Load(uploadAsset);
           ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            string actionName = "myFileLink";
            UserCustomAction scriptAction = ctx.Web.UserCustomActions.Add();
            scriptAction.Location = "ScriptLink";
            scriptAction.Sequence = 100;
            scriptAction.ScriptSrc = web.Url + iframeJsUrl;


            scriptAction.Name = actionName;
            scriptAction.Update();
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

           console.log("error message" +ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is a different thing. Find about it in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets the CultureInfo object that represents the culture used
>   by the current thread.

According to your question's description, you need the culture of your current web. So can try following:

```
    private uint GetCultureOfTheWeb(ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        var web = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(web.RegionalSettings);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        return web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId;
    }
```

It will always give `LocaleId`. From this `LocaleId`, culture can be decided.

- For English, it will return `1033`
- For Norwegian, it will return `1044`

Now your code can be changed like following.

```
 var currentWebCulture = GetCultureOfTheWeb(clientContext);
 if (currentWebCulture == 1033) {
     lib = "Site Assets";
 } else if (currentWebCulture == 1044) {
     lib = "Nettstedsobjekter";
 }
```